# How to make my protocol token erc20 compatible?

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I'm currently working on a DeFi blockchain project and we need to be listed on DEX. How can I make sure my token is ERC20 compatible and compliant to DEX norms?

Comment: Also make sure to use OpenZeppelin's [SafeERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/5a00628ed3d6ce3154cee4d2cc93fad920e8ea30/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol) if you want to support USDT. See what is the [Missing return value bug](https://medium.com/coinmonks/missing-return-value-bug-at-least-130-tokens-affected-d67bf08521ca).

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the ERC20 standard - it requires the implementation of couple of functions such as:

- `totalSupply()`
- `balanceOf()`
- `transfer()`
- `approve()`
- `transferFrom()`

You should check the [OpenZeppelin docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/) to read about the standards for [ERC20 (github)](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) and the ERC20 interface [IERC20 (github)](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol).

You can inherit from the OpenZeppelin contracts, this will make your token ERC20 compatible. But you could also import the interface and implement the functions yourself.

Simple demo example with ERC20:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("My Token", "MYT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000000000000000);
    }
}
```